# If integral of every continuous function is zero then the measure is zero

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Here's what I am trying to prove:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mu$ be a finite signed Borel measure on $X$. Suppose that
\begin{align*}
\int f d\mu =0
\end{align*}
for every continuous function $f$. Then $\mu$ is the zero measure.

---

Here's my take on it: If $\mu$ is an unsigned measure then then we have that
$\int \chi_{X} d\mu = 0$ where $\chi_X$ is the characteristic function of $X$. Hence, we have that $\mu(X)=0$ and that forces that $\mu=0$. However, I do not see how this is true for a finite signed measure.

By Hahn Decomposition Theorem, there exists positive set $P$ and a negative set $N$ such that $X$ is the disjoint union of $P$ and $N$. However, I cannot conclude that $\chi_P$ and $\chi_N$ are continuous to do the same as in the case of unsigned measure.

Hints are appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there are no further hypotheses on the space? E.g. that it is Hausdorff, normal, ...

Comment: @FShrike This is a question that I formulated. The book "Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions" by Hoffman makes this claim when $X$ is the unit circle $\{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| = 1 \}$ with the usual topology (not the subspace topology!) on it but I do not know how to prove it in the case of the unit circle as well...

Comment: @ashK could you please say what page comtains this statement?